# How to introduce friction between model joints?

Tags: gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi my question is that how I can introduce friction in model joints. The parameter 0.0 is there but it is working in same way as 1.0. What is the right way to introduce friction according to friction coefficient?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2293/how-to-introduce-friction-between-model-joints?/) by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Friction in joints is currently not implemented:
https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/381/ode-joints-dont-support-friction-parameter

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-11**:
Thanks @nkoenig